# Every 24h, network connectivity ceases

Tags: networking, hardware

Every day my Raspberry Pi 4 4GB loses ethernet (wired) network connectivity (I don't use WiFi on the device). The device is otherwise still functional, but no matter whether I down/up the interface, restart networking with `service networking restart`, un/replug the network cable, or even `shutdown -r now` the device, the network does not return. The device must be fully halted `shutdown -hP now`, power pulled, and power returned for the network to also return.

Since I started taking notice of exactly when it went down (I have remote endpoint monitoring polling every 5 minutes), I've finally determined it is exactly 24h after the last power up that the network dies.

I can't find anything in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`, beyond software components failing to connect to things. `avahi-daemon` even mentions releasing IP addresses a while after it is clear the network has already gone, but no event to explain why.

Pi's uses:

- Docker for these images: Plex, Netdata, Pi Hole, Tautulli, Traefik, among others
- `autossh` to keep a tunnel to a remote server up

I can't figure it out. I don't know where else to look. Short of attempting to boot this same system from another of the exact same model of Pi I have, I don't know what other investigation to perform.

**EDIT 20201231**: Using a combination of:

- `tcpdump` on the DHCP server/router
- changing the DHCP lifetime in DHCP server to something short to ease diagnosis (5 minutes/300 seconds)
- tracking the IP address lifetime on the Raspberry Pi (`watch 'sudo ip addr | grep -A 3 eth0:'` and watching 'preferred_lft')
- `sudo dcpdump -i /dev/eth0`

...I've been able to see that the device does not appear to send any further DHCP packets over eth0/into the switch/to the router after boot. The preferred_lft gets to 0sec and the address is deprecated, then once valid_lft ticks through, the IPv4 address is dropped.

In a moment of weird thought, I wondered what would happen if I disabled the docker daemon using `sudo systemctl disable docker`, and after a reboot, I could see that the address would never get close to expiring (as is supposed to happen) and the DHCP lease would be renewed as intended. So clearly there is something about the Docker setup that is causing DHCP to go awry, hence requiring a reboot.

I'll have to play around with my Docker stacks (using docker-compose.yml files and running about 5-6 stacks) to make sure nothing untoward is in there. It may even be that a certain container has an incompatibility with the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Your DHCP server may only issue 24 hour allocations, but without diagnostics who knows. One thing is certain `service networking restart` won't help as it isn't normally used. What does `ip a && ip r` show

Comment: DHCP leases being limited in time is completely normal. However, once the IP address expires, the Pi should automatically request and obtain a new one.

Comment: Test with a fresh flashed Raspberry Pi OS Lite. If it also fails after 24h, then it's not a problem of the RasPi.

Comment: @Milliways DHCP lease from USG is 24h, but no other device (including 2 other RPI4s) don't have any trouble renewing their lease. And it didn't used to in the past. Additionally, per edit, I'm using Docker on it; so `ip a` returns the plethora of virtual/bridge NICs and their IPs. `ifconfig` has been what I've checked during outages in the past and as far as it is concerned, the eth0 interface is up, despite no longer having IP config.

Comment: @Ingo or perhaps it would suggest a hardware problem on this specific Pi. I've replaced every network device it connects/relies on since having this problem and none of it has changed the RPI's 24h death march

Comment: What about the lights? An eth interface being potentially "up" is a reflection of the state of the physical layer, and doesn't imply "connected" inet wise.  Anyway, you should have solid lights on both sides of the jack -- obviously you can check this yourself while it is in a working state vs. after 24 hours.  If those are different, it implies something about how far down the problem exists.

Comment: @goldilocks I seem to recall the lights still being on and blinking when the "outage" occurs. Will take more explicit notice and video of fine/not fine to compare.

Comment: If they are actually *blinking* (erratically) that indicates activity -- although whether it could be the activity of a failure at the eth level or of faulty hardware I dunno...not an expert.

Comment: Yes, I would've expected so. But that could simply mean that the switch is still sending frames to the port, because that's where it expects them to go. Will fiddle around with the PHY next outage and see if anything jumps out.

Comment: @Ashley A hardware problem is very unlikely. Typical for hardware errors is that they occur randomly and not in a reproducible fixed time interval.

Comment: for quicker debugging, can you set the length of DHCP lease on your DHCP server to something like 1 hour (or even less) - will also determine if it's a DHCP issue if it fails quicker

Comment: Good suggestion @jaromanda - will try that next I get the opportunity

Comment: @JaromandaX well I'll be damned... set DHCP lease timeout to 3600s/1hr before the most recent reboot and... 1hr later the machine dropped off the network. This doesn't explain why a warm reboot doesn't fix this, though. And why it is failing at all compared to the other Pis of the same model

Comment: at least now it's clear it's some sort of DHCP issue - does a fresh install of Rpi OS also fail?

Comment: The other devices on this network have no issue. Including 3 other Pi4. But yeah I think it's time I reinstall. I've got a spare SD card. If we know this is the issue, how would we track down *why* the DHCP lease expiring is an issue?

Comment: Some updates. Looks like Docker is doing something weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that an update to the Raspberry Pi OS, the Raspberry Pi firmware, or the Realtek NIC firmware fixed this issue at some point mid January 2021 onwards. It no longer occurs.